# How to Convert a UTC datetime to BST Time British Summer Time (BST) Laravel Carbon

Tags: laravel, php-carbon

I am trying to convert UTC time to BST. It shows incorrect results if I am correct.

```
$timestamp =  '2020-03-30 16:34:00';
$date = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp, 'Europe/London');
$date->tz('BST');

$bst =  $date->toDateTimeString();
```

Above code outputs **2020-03-30 15:34:00**. Note that BST is one hour less in the output.

Comment: Thanks guys, As an alternative, I used MySQL CONVERT_TZ function to achieve this.
    CONVERT_TZ(datetime_column, 'UTC', 'Europe/London');

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP doesn't seem to support BST. It's not on the list of supported timezones of [Europe](https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.europe.php) or [other timezones](https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.others.php). I'm not sure why it doesn't throw an exception when you use `BST`, but the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php) say here that:

> The behavior of timezones not listed here is undefined.

It's also evident that "BST" doesn't work correctly because when you create time with the `BST` timezone, the output always says `+00:00`, even in the summer months:

```
>>> $date = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2020-01-30 16:34:00', 'BST');
=> Carbon\Carbon @1580402040 {#3261
     date: 2020-01-30 16:34:00.0 +00:00,
   }
>>> $date = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2020-05-30 16:34:00', 'BST');
=> Carbon\Carbon @1590856440 {#3258
     date: 2020-05-30 16:34:00.0 +00:00,
   }
```

However, when you use the `Europe/London` timezone, the output will say `+00:00` (essentially 'UTC') in the winter months and `+01:00` (essentially 'BST') in the summer months:

```
>>> $date = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2020-01-30 16:34:00', 'Europe/London');
=> Carbon\Carbon @1580402040 {#3256
     date: 2020-01-30 16:34:00.0 Europe/London (+00:00),
   }
>>> $date = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2020-05-30 16:34:00', 'Europe/London');
=> Carbon\Carbon @1590852840 {#3251
     date: 2020-05-30 16:34:00.0 Europe/London (+01:00),
   }
```

So the location-based timezones already take daylight savings into account.

Comment: I just want to explain, but you are better +1

Comment: Great, Nicely explained. 
Thanks, guys I had to use an alternative way to achieve this (using MySQL).

Comment: BST is not a timezone, it is just the way Brits refer to daylight savings (ie. it is only applicable during the summer months - whereas a timezone applies year round). So it is not surprising that PHP does not support it.